# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PySide2.QtWebKitWidgets'

Tags: python, python-3.x, conda, pyside2

I have installed Anaconda environment on CentOS and Windows.
And have installed PySide2 using conda.

The problem is my project run well in CentOS, but in Windows, it shows "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PySide2.QtWebKitWidgets'" when run server.

Conda, pyhon, pip, PySide2 and PyQt5 's version are same in Both OS.

I don't know what's wrong?

Comment: did you find any solution to this?*

Comment: Wich conda version are you using? It appears to be a conflict of web engine widget and future support. You are looking for QtWebKit, but the alternative is QtWebEngine, which is what Qt apparently has committed to supporting in the future, but that's not available yet. So I think Anaconda code and yours got caught in the middle in different plattform versions.

Answer (score 1):

I experienced the same problem when creating a sample app using pyside2 where the error message was as follows:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "browse.py", line 7, in 
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/shiboken2/files.dir/shibokensupport/**feature**.py", line 146, in _import
File "/home/pjm/prj/eis3/gui/browser.py", line 15, in 
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/shiboken2/files.dir/shibokensupport/**feature**.py", line 146, in _import
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PySide2.QtWebKitWidgets'

So the issue is that the version of designer or pyside2-uic is using the old QtWebKitWidgets rather than what I believe is the more modern QtWebEngineView.

I actually think it is my version of designer which produces the following extract:

```
  <customwidget>
   <class>QWebView</class>
   <extends>QWidget</extends>
   <header>QtWebKitWidgets/QWebView</header>
  </customwidget>
```

In any event I "fixed" this by means of a sed script in a makefile as follows:

```
browser.py: browser.ui makefile
    pyside2-uic  $< --output temp.txt
    cat temp.txt | sed s/QtWebKitWidgets/QtWebEngineWidgets/g | sed s/QWebView/QWebEngineView/g > $@
```

My version of designer was 5.11.3 which is installed on debian which may explain this.  In short I think the problem may be the version of designer that was used to create the ui file.

Answer (score 0):

`QtWebkit` is deprecated, you can try to build `PySide2` from scratch enabling the module in the [CMakeLists.txt](https://code.qt.io/cgit/pyside/pyside-setup.git/tree/sources/pyside2/CMakeLists.txt#n366) file.